# How to insert data into two typed datasets without violating foreign key constraints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset

Should I just use two different inserts starting with the parent or is there a better way?

Comment: I am not really having a problem, I am just wondering if there is a better way to do it. Presently I am simply using the Insert commands that were auto-generated by the typed datasets one by one starting with the parent.

For example, if I have 3 tables with foreign key relationships, I use the Insert statement for the uppermost parent first, the Insert statement for the dataset with a fk from the first parent next, and finally the Insert statement for the dataset with a fk from the second parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporally disable the constrains and insert all data then enable them again using the [EnforceConstraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.enforceconstraints.aspx) property.

```
myDataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;

// insert to parent and child. insert order does not matter since constraints are
// disabled

myDataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
```